# Understanding the differences between mov and lea instructions in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, mov

I'm trying to understand the differences between the `mov` and `lea` instructions in x86 assembly language. I've written a simple assembly code snippet , and I've added comments to explain my understanding of these instructions.

```
.data
num: .int 2     # Declare an integer variable num with value 2

.text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl num, %eax # num stores an address, take the value inside that address into eax
    movl $num, %ebx # num stores an address, $ tells us to take the address itself into ebx
    leal num, %ecx # num stores an address, take the address itself into ecx (lea)

    #initialize
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx

    movl $num, %edx # num stores an address, take the address itself into edx
    movl %edx, %eax # edx is an address, take the value inside that address into eax
    leal (%edx), %ecx # () tells us to go to the address inside edx, take the address itself into ecx (lea)
    movl (%edx), %ebx # () tells us to go to the address inside edx, take the value inside that address into ebx

    # Exit
    movl $1, %eax     # System call number for exit
    xorl %ebx, %ebx   # Exit status 0
    int $0x80         # Invoke the syscall
```

However, I'm a bit confused about how these instructions work with registers. and I'll be glad if someone will give me his explanation.

Comment: Quick comment: `num` is a label and represents an address, a constant global address.  Some assemblers know that a label such as `num` is data declared as `int` but many others don't, and only know that `num` itself is a constant address.  Then it is up to the `l` in `movl` and the target register to set the size of the memory access.  So you could do `movw num, ax` to perform a 16-bit access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your comments are fine.
Others may need some rewording:

> ```
> movl %edx, %eax # edx is an address, take the value inside that address into eax
> ```

"**take the value inside that address**"
This just puts a copy of what is in the EDX register into the EAX register. The fact that in this case EDX contains an address is of no importance.

> ```
> leal (%edx), %ecx # () tells us to go to the address inside edx, take the address itself into ecx (lea)
> ```

"**go to the address inside**"
We're not *going* to an address. The CPU calculates the address that the leftmost operand represents and stores it as such into the destination register ECX.

---

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78251018/understanding-the-differences-between-mov-and-lea-instructions-in-x86-assembly/78251378#comment137957428_78251378):

> just to make sure, when i write `movl num, %eax`, assembly see num as adress, for example its just `movl 0x001000, %eax`. can i say the same for this: `movl %eax, %eax`. is just `movl 0x002000, %eax`.

No, you can't say the same:
The `movl %eax, %eax` instruction is a copy from one register to another. And since source and destination are the same register it is also a 'silly' operation. Now if you know that EAX contains the value 0x002000, what you wrote (`movl 0x002000, %eax`) is certainly not the same as that mere register copy. **In your assembler the absence of the $ prefix makes the instruction de-reference**, and thus `movl 0x002000, %eax` will fetch a dword from the memory at the address 0x002000.

In summary and based on *num* equaling 0x001000 and EAX equaling 0x002000:

```
movl num, %eax       fetches a dword at address 0x001000  
movl 0x001000, %eax  fetches a dword at address 0x001000  
movl %eax, %eax      copies register EAX to itself  
movl 0x002000, %eax  fetches a dword at address 0x002000
```

Now add the **$** prefix and

```
movl $0x002000, %eax stores the number 0x002000 in the EAX register
```

making this instruction the equivalent of `movl %eax, %eax`.

Comment: can i even say that edx is an adress and i go into it?

Comment: @AlfaHores No problem with saying that EDX *is* an address, but 'going into it' makes no sense. You can 'use' its value, you can 'clear' the register,... Only in an instruction that uses de-referencing like `movl (%edx), %ebx` could you maybe say 'going into it'.

Comment: ok i think i got you. just to make sure, when i write ``movl num, %eax``, assembly see num as adress, for example its just ``movl 0x001000, %eax.``
can i say the same for this: ``movl %eax, %eax.`` is just ``movl 0x002000, %eax.`` @SepRoland